# Azure Bot Framework with Cortana Skill using C#

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, cortana

I am new to C# and Bot Framework. I need to set up a small poc where I have to do a sample registration using Cortana, C# and SQL. Can anyone of you help me out in this?

Comment: You are **new** but you can search/learn at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is *literally* the first post I found when copying the title of your post into Google: [Build a speech-enabled bot with Cortana skills](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-cortana-skill?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

> Creating a Cortana skill using Bot Framework requires very little Cortana-specific knowledge and primarily consists of building a bot. One of the likely key differences from other bots that you may have created in the past is that Cortana has both a visual and an audio component. For the visual component, Cortana provides an area of the canvas for rendering content such as cards. For the audio component, you provide text or SSML in your bot's messages, which Cortana reads to the user, giving your bot a voice.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to create bot application in c# and access SQL database, you can try:

1) [Bot Builder SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-overview?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) is easy to use and leverages C# to provide a familiar way for .NET developers to write bots.

2)to access SQL database, you can use [ADO.NET technologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples) or [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx). And here is [an example](https://github.com/JasonSowers/DatabaseBotExample) of EF in a bot, you can refer to it.

Besides, to configure Cortana channel, you can refer to this article: ["Connect a bot to Cortana"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-cortana?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

Comment: I need a registration form where user uses Cortana to register into my application. Where I didn't found anywhere. I need a sample solution as a reference.

Comment: If you want that your bot could provide registration form and user can use Cortana to connect your bot to do registration, you can use [Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#adaptive-card) with input fields and button to build a registration form.